# optimizing my Benfold's law program

Tags: python

```
lines=[]
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0
count4 = 0
count5 = 0
count6 = 0
count7 = 0
count8 = 0
count9 = 0
allcount = 0

with open('city_all.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        lines.append(line.strip())

for x in range(0,len(lines)):
    if lines[x].isdigit():
        allcount+=1
        string = lines[x]
        if string[0]=="1":
            count1+=1
        elif string[0]=="2":
            count2+=1
        elif string[0]=="3":
            count3+=1
        elif string[0]=="4":
            count4+=1
        elif string[0]=="5":
            count5+=1
        elif string[0]=="6":
            count6+=1
        elif string[0]=="7":
            count7+=1
        elif string[0]=="8":
            count8+=1
        elif string[0]=="9":
            count9+=1

print(count1/allcount)
print('{:.1%}'.format(count1/allcount))
```

Wondering if there is anyway to not have to declare all my variables, and compact all the if statements?Trying to make a program to help compute Benfold's law, so I am putting a txt file into a list, then going through each element and checking what the starting digit is.

Comment: `counts = [0 for _ in range (10) ]`? And instead of `countX = Y` use `counts[X] = Y`.

Comment: ooo thanks, that makes sense, appreciate it!

Comment: This also lets you simplify if, now all you need to do is check if `string[0]` is in the appropriate range, and if so, increment `count[string[0]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it a bit:

```
counts = [0 for _ in range (10) ]

with open('city_all.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in (x.strip () for x in f):
        if line.isdigit():
            allcount += 1
            try: counts[int(line)] += 1
            except IndexError: pass
```

Comment: @adsmith Why increment if it isn't a digit?

Comment: @StephenTG I don't know, because I misread the original code and thought that's what he was doing ;). I deleted my original comment to save face, but I'll leave this one to remind me of my shame lol

Comment: Two comments: 1. `count`/`counts` typo, 2. I think `[0]*10` is much easier on the eyes (and memory) than a list comprehension.

Comment: @Pompei2 Thank you. Fixed the typo. I left the LC, because otherwise it might lead someone to use the same multiplication with lists containing mutable elements like `[[]] * 10`.

Comment: Actually, there's an additional problem: if `line` contains valid integers outside the range, like `-1` or `99`, this code will raise an exception while the original code will just use the first digit. This is important since it's about Benfold's law!

Comment: No, see the edit of my comment. `counts[int(line[0])]` will fix it for positive integers. For correctly handling negative integers, you'll need another test, but given the code is for Benfold's law, I guess negative numbers don't matter.